# Nebular Ngx-admin , how can i change width of nb-auth-block from 35 rem to full width

Tags: angular, sass, nebular, ngx-admin

I created a new component for login and register, and i want to change the width of the content, but the nb-auth-block tag has always max-width:35rem;
I tried to change it in auth.component.scss but didn't work, and everywhere in code where it was 35rem.

How can i change the width of nb-auth-block to full-width?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem adding

```
nb-auth-block{
  max-width: inherit!important;
}
```

in src\app@theme\styles\styles.scss